# How to implement information from Retrofit into a viewPager2 layout widgets

Tags: android, retrofit, carousel, rest, android-viewpager2

So I'm building this Carousel project that shows an image and some text on the app. I've gotten the structure down by building a prototype. I was able to use Retrofit to call the information from the RestAPI on my terminal as well. But where I have been really stuck at is trying to get the info to show in the container, where I want it to show. I've tried a slew of ways to approach it, but to no avail. Below is the code I have now, which is showing images and text that I put in it. Along with the Retrofit classes. I've been at it for three days and I'm not sure what to do. If anyone has an idea or can help, I'll be extremely thankful.

The API (Retrofit)

```
package com.examples.carousel.api

import com.examples.carousel.CarouselItem
import com.examples.carousel.utli.Constants.Companion.BASE_URL
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface FlickrApi {
    @GET("services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList" +
            "&api_key=(private)" +
            "&format=json" +
            "&nojsoncallback=1" +
            "&extras=url_s")

     fun getCarouselItem() : Call<List<CarouselItem>>

    companion object {
        fun create() : FlickrApi {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(FlickrApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

The Model (The comment out code is for the info I want from the api)

```
package com.examples.carousel


data class CarouselItem internal constructor(
//    var title: String,
//    var id: String,
//    var url_s: String

    var image: Int,
    var title2: String
    ) {

}
```

The Adapter

```
package com.examples.carousel

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView


class ItemAdapter internal constructor(carouselItems: MutableList<CarouselItem>,  viewPager2: ViewPager2) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemPagerViewHolder>() {


    private val carouselItems: List<CarouselItem>
    private val viewPager2: ViewPager2

    init {
        this.carouselItems = carouselItems
        this.viewPager2 = viewPager2
    }

    class ItemPagerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val photo: RoundedImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture)
        private val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_name)

        fun image(carouselItem: CarouselItem) {
            photo.setImageResource(carouselItem.image)
        }

        fun text(carouselItem: CarouselItem) {
            title.text = carouselItem.title2
        }

            }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemPagerViewHolder {
        return ItemPagerViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.carousel_item_container,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.image(carouselItems[position])
        holder.text(carouselItems[position])
        if (position == carouselItems.size - 2) {
            viewPager2.post(runnable)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return carouselItems.size
    }

    private val runnable = Runnable {
        carouselItems.addAll(carouselItems)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

The MainActivity

```
package com.examples.carousel


import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.CompositePageTransformer
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.MarginPageTransformer
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.examples.carousel.api.FlickrApi
import com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import kotlin.math.abs


class CarouselActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carousel)

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager_ImageSlider)
        supportActionBar?.hide()


        val multipleItems: MutableList<CarouselItem> = ArrayList()
        multipleItems.add(CarouselItem(R.drawable.bcw_38,"Image 1"))
        multipleItems.add(CarouselItem(R.drawable.bcw_39,"Image 2"))
        multipleItems.add(CarouselItem(R.drawable.bcw_40,"Image 3"))
        multipleItems.add(CarouselItem(R.drawable.bcw_45,"Image 4"))
        multipleItems.add(CarouselItem(R.drawable.bcw_50,"Image 5"))
        multipleItems.add(CarouselItem(R.drawable.bcw_53,"Image 6"))


        viewPager.adapter = ItemAdapter(multipleItems,viewPager)

        viewPager.clipToPadding = false
        viewPager.clipChildren = false
        viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        viewPager.getChildAt(0).overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER

        val compositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()
        compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(30))
        compositePageTransformer.addTransformer { page, position ->
            val r = 1 - abs(position)
            page.scaleY = 0.85f + r * 0.25f
        }

        viewPager.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer)

//
//        val apiInterface = FlickrApi.create().getCarouselItem()
//
//        apiInterface.enqueue(object: Callback<List<CarouselItem>> {
//            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<CarouselItem>>, t: Throwable) {
//
//            }
//
//            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<CarouselItem>>, response: Response<List<CarouselItem>>) {
//
//                if (response.body() != null){
//                  itemAdapter.setItemListItems(response.body()!!)
//
//                }
//            }
//        })


    }

}
```

The XML Files:

The ViewPager2 layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#232323"
                                                   android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager_ImageSlider"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="70dp"
            android:paddingEnd="70dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="80dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/osa_playlist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="25sp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Container

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/container" android:background="#232323">
    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="550dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:riv_corner_radius="12dp" tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/photo_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="TEXT TEXT" android:textSize="36sp" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picture" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="230dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    //For the Carousel Container
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    //For Retrofit and Gson
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    }
```

*Its not the Internet permission, it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

itemAdapter.setItemListItems(response.body()!!) instead of calling adapters method, write your own method which updates the list:
private val carouselItems: List,
make this list mutable and write method:

```
public fun updateList(val items: List<CarouselItem>){
   carouselItems.clear()
   carouselItems.addAll(items)
   notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: So this would be in the Adapter. And then call it within the onResponse method I'm assuming?

Comment: @OEThe11 yes, exactly

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how to implement update list function exactly?:

Comment: change type of your field carouselItems to MutableList<CarouselItem>. In constructor pass empty list and then when you get response from retrofit call, update method of adapter which I wrote in the answer